# REACT radio and checkbox input combined?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, checkboxlist

I have several survey question from an array. All questions are radio buttons but there is one question with choices 'a, b, c, d or e'. They can select a through d but e will override other selections. How do I combine checkbox and radio buttons.

The catch is that I need to do it in React.

```
<Button
    key={this.props.key}
    id={this.props.survHeader}
    className={`${this.props.className[this.props.index]} survChkBtn`}
    color={this.props.color[this.props.index]}
    onClick={() => this.props.onClickHandle(this.props.selectionType === 
        "checkbox" ? this.props.answer : this.props.data_value)}
    value={this.props.data_value}
    active = {this.props.selectionType ==="radio" ? this.props.active === 
         this.props.data_value : this.state.active.includes(this.props.answer) }
    data_value = {this.props.data_value}
>
    <h4 className="btnAnswer">{this.props.answer}</h4>
  </Button>
```

Comment: Are you able to link your component code?

Comment: Control it in your state: if each button is a controlled input, and you correctly set the state values, the DOM elements will behave correctly.